# Xcode won't allow me to archive my project one more time

Tags: ios, xcode8, archive, appstore-approval

So, I have a question about why xcode wont let me archive the same project again. My app was recently rejected by the app store for a reason that I have now fixed. So I wanted to submit another build and to do that I went to archive my project once again. Unfortunately xcode did not allow me to perform this action because I had archived my project before when I was shipping my app to the app store. I assumed that renaming this archive version would resolve this issue but I do not know how to. So basically what I am asking is how do I submit a new build for my app to the app store with a previous build already submitted. Do I delete my previous archive?

The error apple gives me says you can't archive this project again because a similar one already exists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I just added the error to my question

Comment: Did you change the version/build numbers?

Comment: @RohanVasishth The build number is right under version number in the General tab. Check out [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html)

Comment: So do I have to change the build number/version in my info.plist?

Comment: You don't need to edit the plist by hand if that's what you are asking. Go to the Project Navigator, select your project at the very top of the tree, go to Targets and also select there your project. In the General tab, under Identity, change Version and/or Build. If this works I can turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same issue. Solved by increasing the build number by one.

[image]

Hope it helps!